# unusual output, brew update verbosely outputs stash and restore changes on terminal

Tags: git, terminal, homebrew, osx-yosemite, osx-elcapitan

unusual output in brew update command

```
     ➜  ~  brew update
     Stashing your changes:
     M README.md
     M apple-gcc42.rb
     M awk.rb
     M bzip2.rb
     M diffstat.rb
     M diffutils.rb
     M ed.rb
     M expect.rb
     M file-formula.rb
     M gdb.rb
     M gpatch.rb
     M gperf.rb
     M grep.rb
     M groff.rb
     M gzip.rb
     M heimdal.rb
     M krb5.rb
     M lapack.rb
     M less.rb
     M libedit.rb
     M libiconv.rb
     M libpcap.rb
     M lsof.rb
     M m4.rb
     M make.rb
     M nano.rb
     M ncurses.rb
     M openldap.rb
     M openssh.rb
     M rsync.rb
     M xar.rb
     M zlib.rb
    Restored your changes:
     M README.md
     M apple-gcc42.rb
     M awk.rb
     M bzip2.rb
     M diffstat.rb
     M diffutils.rb
     M ed.rb
     M expect.rb
     M file-formula.rb
     M gdb.rb
     M krb5.rb
     M lapack.rb
     M less.rb
     M libedit.rb
     M libiconv.rb
     M libpcap.rb
     M lsof.rb
     M m4.rb
     M make.rb
     M nano.rb
     M ncurses.rb
     M openldap.rb
     M openssh.rb
     M rsync.rb
     M screen.rb
     M tcl-tk.rb
     M tcpdump.rb
     M units.rb
     M unzip.rb
     M whois.rb
     M xar.rb
     M zlib.rb
    Stashing your changes:
     M Abstract/abstract-php-extension.rb
     M Abstract/abstract-php-version.rb
     M Abstract/abstract-php.rb
     M "Contributions/Using FPM.md"
     M Formula/behat.rb
     M Formula/boris.rb
     M Formula/box.rb
     M Formula/brew-php-switcher.rb
     M Formula/chphp.rb
     M Formula/codeception.rb
     M Formula/composer.rb
     M Formula/drupal-code-sniffer.rb
     M Formula/drush.rb
     M Formula/envoy.rb
     M Formula/ezcomponents.rb
     M Formula/foreman.rb
     M Formula/libsphinxclient.rb
     M Formula/mondrian.rb
     M Formula/php53-amqp.rb
     M Formula/php53-apc.rb
     M Formula/php53-apcu.rb
     M Formula/php53-binpack.rb
     M Formula/php53-blitz.rb
     M Formula/php53-boxwood.rb
     M Formula/php53-chdb.rb
     M Formula/php53-couchbase.rb
     M Formula/php53-crypto.rb
     M Formula/php53-dbase.rb
     M Formula/php53-dbus.rb
     M Formula/php53-dmtx.rb
     M Formula/php53-eio.rb
     M Formula/php53-gearman.rb
     M Formula/php53-geoip.rb
     M Formula/php53-gmagick.rb
     M Formula/php53-graphdat.rb
     M Formula/php53-hprose.rb
     M Formula/php53-htscanner.rb
     M Formula/php53-http.rb
     M Formula/php53-igbinary.rb
     M Formula/php53-imagick.rb
     M Formula/php53-intl.rb
     M Formula/php53-ioncubeloader.rb
     M Formula/php53-jsmin.rb
     M Formula/php53-judy.rb
     M Formula/php53-leveldb.rb
     M Formula/php53-libevent.rb
     M Formula/php53-libsodium.rb
     M Formula/php53-libvirt.rb
     M Formula/php53-lz4.rb
     M Formula/php53-lzf.rb
     M Formula/php53-magickwand.rb
     M Formula/php53-mailparse.rb
     M Formula/php53-mcrypt.rb
     M Formula/php53-mecab.rb
     M Formula/php53-memcache.rb
     M Formula/php53-memcached.rb
     M Formula/php53-midgard2.rb
     M Formula/php53-mongo.rb
     M Formula/php53-mosquitto.rb
     M Formula/wp-cli.rb
     M README.md
     M Requirements/composer-requirement.rb
     M Requirements/homebrew-php-requirement.rb
     M Requirements/phar-building-requirement.rb
     M Requirements/phar-requirement.rb
     M Requirements/php-meta-requirement.rb
    Restored your changes:
     M Abstract/abstract-php-extension.rb
     M Abstract/abstract-php-version.rb
     M Abstract/abstract-php.rb
     M "Contributions/Using FPM.md"
     M Formula/behat.rb
     M Formula/boris.rb
     M Formula/box.rb
     M Formula/brew-php-switcher.rb
     M Formula/chphp.rb
     M Formula/codeception.rb
     M Formula/composer.rb
     M Formula/drupal-code-sniffer.rb
     M Formula/drush.rb
     M Formula/envoy.rb
     M Formula/ezcomponents.rb
     M Formula/foreman.rb
     M Formula/libsphinxclient.rb
     M Formula/mondrian.rb
     M Formula/pdepend.rb
     M Formula/pharcc.rb
     M Formula/php-build.rb
     M Formula/php-code-sniffer.rb
     M Formula/php-cs-fixer.rb
     M Formula/php-install.rb
     M Formula/php-version.rb
     M Formula/php53-amqp.rb
     M Formula/php53-apc.rb
     M Formula/php53-apcu.rb
     M Formula/php53-binpack.rb
     M Formula/php53-blitz.rb
     M Formula/php53-boxwood.rb
     M Formula/php53-chdb.rb
     M Formula/php53-couchbase.rb
     M Formula/php53-crypto.rb
     M Formula/php53-dbase.rb
     M Formula/php53-dbus.rb
     M Formula/php53-dmtx.rb
     M Formula/php53-eio.rb
     M Formula/php53-gearman.rb
     M Formula/php53-geoip.rb
     M Formula/php53-gmagick.rb
     M Formula/php53-graphdat.rb
     M Formula/php53-hprose.rb
     M Formula/php53-htscanner.rb
     M Formula/php53-http.rb
     M Formula/php53-igbinary.rb
     M Formula/php53-imagick.rb
     M Formula/php53-intl.rb
     M Formula/php53-ioncubeloader.rb
     M Formula/php53-jsmin.rb
     M Formula/php54-graphdat.rb
     M Formula/php54-zmq.rb
     M Formula/php54-zookeeper.rb
     M Formula/php54.rb
     M Formula/php55-amqp.rb
     M Formula/php55-apcu.rb
     M Formula/php55-augmentedtypes.rb
     M Formula/php55-binpack.rb
     M Formula/php55-blitz.rb
     M Formula/php55-boxwood.rb
     M Formula/php55-chdb.rb
     M Formula/php55-couchbase.rb
     M Formula/php55-crypto.rb
     M Formula/php55-dbase.rb
     M Formula/php55-dbus.rb
     M Formula/php55-dmtx.rb
     M Formula/php55-eio.rb
     M Formula/php55-ev.rb
     M Formula/php55-event.rb
     M Formula/php55-gearman.rb
     M Formula/php55-geoip.rb
     M Formula/php55-gmagick.rb
     M Formula/php55-graphdat.rb
     M Formula/php55-hprose.rb
     M Formula/php55-htscanner.rb
     M Formula/php55-http.rb
     M Formula/php55-igbinary.rb
     M Formula/php55-imagick.rb
     M Formula/php55-intl.rb
     M Formula/php55-ioncubeloader.rb
     M Formula/php55-jsmin.rb
     M Formula/php55-judy.rb
     M Formula/php55-leveldb.rb
     M Formula/php55-libevent.rb
     M Formula/php55-libsodium.rb
     M Formula/php55-libvirt.rb
     M Formula/php55-lz4.rb
     M Formula/php55-lzf.rb
     M Formula/php55-magickwand.rb
     M Formula/php55-mailparse.rb
     M Formula/php55-mcrypt.rb
     M Formula/php55-mecab.rb
     M Formula/php55-memcache.rb
     M Formula/php55-memcached.rb
     M Formula/php55-midgard2.rb
     M Formula/php55-mongo.rb
     M Formula/php55-mosquitto.rb
     M Formula/php55-msgpack.rb
     M Formula/php55-mysqlnd_ms.rb
     M Formula/php55-oauth.rb
     M Formula/php55-opcache.rb
     M Formula/php55-parsekit.rb
     M Formula/php55-pcntl.rb
     M Formula/php55-pdflib.rb
     M Formula/php55-pdo-dblib.rb
     M Formula/php55-pdo-pgsql.rb
     M Formula/php55-phalcon.rb
     M Formula/php55-pimple.rb
     M Formula/php55-proctitle.rb
     M Formula/php55-propro.rb
     M Formula/php55-protobuf.rb
     M Formula/php55-pspell.rb
     M Formula/php55-pthreads.rb
     M Formula/php55-qr.rb
     M Formula/php55-raphf.rb
     M Formula/php55-redis.rb
     M Formula/php55-redland.rb
     M Formula/php55-riak.rb
     M Formula/php55-runkit.rb
     M Formula/php55-scrypt.rb
     M Formula/php55-snappy.rb
     M Formula/php55-sodium.rb
     M Formula/php55-solr.rb
     M Formula/php55-sphinx.rb
     M Formula/php55-spl-types.rb
     M Formula/php55-ssh2.rb
     M Formula/php55-stats.rb
     M Formula/php55-stemmer.rb
     M Formula/php55-suhosin.rb
     M Formula/php55-sundown.rb
     M Formula/php55-svm.rb
     M Formula/php55-swoole.rb
     M Formula/php55-symfony-debug.rb
     M Formula/php55-thrift.rb
     M Formula/php55-tidy.rb
     M Formula/php55-timezonedb.rb
     M Formula/php55-tokyotyrant.rb
     M Formula/php55-twig.rb
     M Formula/php55-uopz.rb
     M Formula/php55-uploadprogress.rb
     M Formula/php55-uuid.rb
     M Formula/php55-varnish.rb
     M Formula/php55-vld.rb
     M Formula/php55-wbxml.rb
     M Formula/php55-xcache.rb
     M Formula/php55-xdebug.rb
     M Formula/php55-xhgui.rb
     M Formula/php55-xhprof.rb
     M Formula/php55-xmldiff.rb
     M Formula/php55-xxtea.rb
     M Formula/php55-yac.rb
     M Formula/php55-yaf.rb
     M Formula/php55-yaml.rb
     M Formula/php55-yar.rb
     M Formula/php55-yaz.rb
     M Formula/php55-yp.rb
     M Formula/php55-yrmcds.rb
     M Formula/php55-zmq.rb
     M Formula/php55-zookeeper.rb
     M Formula/php55.rb
     M Formula/php56-amqp.rb
     M Formula/php56-apcu.rb
     M Formula/php56-augmentedtypes.rb
     M Formula/php56-binpack.rb
     M Formula/php56-blitz.rb
     M Formula/php56-boxwood.rb
     M Formula/php56-chdb.rb
     M Formula/php56-couchbase.rb
     M Formula/php56-crypto.rb
     M Formula/php56-dbase.rb
     M Formula/php56-dbus.rb
     M Formula/php56-dmtx.rb
     M Formula/php56-eio.rb
     M Formula/php56-ev.rb
     M Formula/php56-event.rb
     M Formula/php56-gearman.rb
     M Formula/php56-geoip.rb
     M Formula/php56-gmagick.rb
     M Formula/php56-graphdat.rb
     M Formula/php56-hprose.rb
     M Formula/php56-htscanner.rb
     M Formula/php56-http.rb
     M Formula/php56-igbinary.rb
     M Formula/php56-imagick.rb
     M Formula/php56-intl.rb
     M Formula/php56-ioncubeloader.rb
     M Formula/php56-jsmin.rb
     M Formula/php56-judy.rb
     M Formula/php56-leveldb.rb
     M Formula/php56-libevent.rb
     M Formula/php56-libsodium.rb
     M Formula/php56-libvirt.rb
     M Formula/php56-lz4.rb
     M Formula/php56-lzf.rb
     M Formula/php56-magickwand.rb
     M Formula/php56-mailparse.rb
     M Formula/php56-mcrypt.rb
     M Formula/php56-mecab.rb
     M Formula/php56-memcache.rb
     M Formula/php56-memcached.rb
     M Formula/php56-midgard2.rb
     M Formula/php56-mongo.rb
     M Formula/php56-mosquitto.rb
     M Formula/php56-msgpack.rb
     M Formula/php56-mysqlnd_ms.rb
     M Formula/php56-oauth.rb
     M Formula/php56-opcache.rb
     M Formula/php56-parsekit.rb
     M Formula/php56-pcntl.rb
     M Formula/php56-pdflib.rb
     M Formula/php56-pdo-dblib.rb
     M Formula/php56-pdo-pgsql.rb
     M Formula/php56-phalcon.rb
     M Formula/php56-pimple.rb
     M Formula/php56-proctitle.rb
     M Formula/php56-propro.rb
     M Formula/php56-protobuf.rb
     M Formula/php56-pspell.rb
     M Formula/php56-pthreads.rb
     M Formula/php56-qr.rb
     M Formula/php56-raphf.rb
     M Formula/php56-redis.rb
     M Formula/php56-redland.rb
     M Formula/php56-riak.rb
     M Formula/php56-runkit.rb
     M Formula/php56-scrypt.rb
     M Formula/php56-snappy.rb
     M Formula/php56-sodium.rb
     M Formula/php56-solr.rb
     M Formula/php56-sphinx.rb
     M Formula/php56-spl-types.rb
     M Formula/php56-ssh2.rb
     M Formula/php56-stats.rb
     M Formula/php56-stemmer.rb
     M Formula/php56-suhosin.rb
     M Formula/php56-sundown.rb
     M Formula/php56-svm.rb
     M Formula/php56-swoole.rb
     M Formula/php56-symfony-debug.rb
     M Formula/php56-thrift.rb
     M Formula/php56-tidy.rb
     M Formula/php56-timezonedb.rb
     M Formula/php56-tokyotyrant.rb
     M Formula/php56-twig.rb
     M Formula/php56-uopz.rb
     M Formula/php56-uploadprogress.rb
     M Formula/php56-uuid.rb
     M Formula/php56-varnish.rb
     M Formula/php56-vld.rb
     M Formula/php56-wbxml.rb
     M Formula/php56-xcache.rb
     M Formula/php56-xdebug.rb
     M Formula/php56-xhgui.rb
     M Formula/php56-xhprof.rb
     M Formula/php56-xmldiff.rb
     M Formula/php56-xxtea.rb
     M Formula/php56-yac.rb
     M Formula/php56-yaf.rb
     M Formula/php56-yaml.rb
     M Formula/php56-yar.rb
     M Formula/php56-yaz.rb
     M Formula/php56-yp.rb
     M Formula/php56-yrmcds.rb
     M Formula/php56-zmq.rb
     M Formula/php56-zookeeper.rb
     M Formula/php56.rb
     M Formula/php70-intl.rb
     M Formula/php70-mcrypt.rb
     M Formula/php70-opcache.rb
     M Formula/php70-pcntl.rb
     M Formula/php70-pdo-dblib.rb
     M Formula/php70-pdo-pgsql.rb
     M Formula/php70-pspell.rb
     M Formula/php70-tidy.rb
     M Formula/php70.rb
     M Formula/phpcpd.rb
     M Formula/phpctags.rb
     M Formula/phpdocumentor.rb
     M Formula/phpdox.rb
     M Formula/phpenv.rb
     M Formula/phplint.rb
     M Formula/phploc.rb
     M Formula/phpmd.rb
     M Formula/phpmetrics.rb
     M Formula/phpmyadmin.rb
     M Formula/phpmyadmin3.rb
     M Formula/phppgadmin.rb
     M Formula/phpsh.rb
     M Formula/phpunit-skeleton-generator.rb
     M Formula/phpunit.rb
     M Formula/sqlformat.rb
     M Formula/virtphp.rb
     M Formula/wp-cli.rb
     M README.md
     M Requirements/composer-requirement.rb
     M Requirements/homebrew-php-requirement.rb
     M Requirements/phar-building-requirement.rb
     M Requirements/phar-requirement.rb
     M Requirements/php-meta-requirement.rb
    Stashing your changes:
     M README.md
     M allegro4.rb
     M android-ndk-r10c.rb
     M android-ndk-r9d.rb
     M ansible14.rb
     M antlr2.rb
     M apache-spark121.rb
     M appledoc20.rb
     M appledoc21.rb
     M appledoc22.rb
     M autoconf213.rb
     M autoconf264.rb
     M automake112.rb
     M bash-completion2.rb
     M bind99.rb
     M bison27.rb
     M boost149.rb
     M boost150.rb
     M boost155.rb
     M boot2docker133.rb
     M boot2docker141.rb
     M camlp5-606.rb
     M cassandra-0.6.rb
     M cassandra10.rb
     M cassandra12.rb
     M cassandra20.rb
     M clojure14.rb
     M cloog-ppl015.rb
     M cloog018.rb
     M cmake28.rb
     M cmake30.rb
     M cmake31.rb
     M coq83.rb
     M cvsps2.rb
     M docker133.rb
     M docker141.rb
     M docker150.rb
     M doxygen1831.rb
     M drush4.rb
     M drush5.rb
     M duplicity06.rb
     M eigen2.rb
     M elasticsearch-0.20.rb
     M elasticsearch090.rb
     M elasticsearch11.rb
     M elasticsearch12.rb
     M elasticsearch13.rb
     M elasticsearch14.rb
     M erlang-r13.rb
     M erlang-r14.rb
     M erlang-r15.rb
     M erlang-r16.rb
     M gawk3.rb
     M gcc43.rb
     M gcc44.rb
     M gcc45.rb
     M gcc46.rb
     M gcc47.rb
     M gcc48.rb
     M gcc49.rb
     M gcc5.rb
     M gdal111.rb
     M gecode373.rb
     M giflib5.rb
     M git-tf-2.0.2.rb
     M glfw2.rb
     M glfw3.rb
     M gmp4.rb
     M gnupg21.rb
     M gnuplot4.rb
     M gnutls34.rb
     M go12.rb
     M go13.rb
     M gradle110.rb
     M gradle112.rb
     M gradle16.rb
     M gradle18.rb
     M gradle20.rb
     M gradle21.rb
     M gradle221.rb
     M grails13.rb
     M grails20.rb
     M grails21.rb
     M grails22.rb
     M grails223.rb
     M grails224.rb
     M grails23.rb
     M gsl114.rb
     M gst-ffmpeg010.rb
     M gst-plugins-bad010.rb
     M gst-plugins-base010.rb
     M gst-plugins-good010.rb
     M gst-plugins-ugly010.rb
     M gst-python010.rb
     M gst-rtsp010.rb
     M gstreamer010.rb
     M guile18.rb
     M hadoop0202.rb
     M hadoop121.rb
     M hadoop25.rb
     M hdf4.rb
     M hive010.rb
     M hive011.rb
     M imagemagick-ruby186.rb
     M isl011.rb
     M isl012.rb
     M isl014.rb
     M jboss-as5.rb
     M jboss-forge1.rb
     M jenkins-lts.rb
     M jetty76.rb
     M jetty8.rb
     M jpeg6b.rb
     M jpeg9.rb
     M json-c010.rb
     M kafka080.rb
     M ledger26.rb
     M leptonica169.rb
     M libcouchbase1.rb
     M libdvdcss12.rb
     M libgee08.rb
     M libmongoclient-legacy.rb
     M libmpc08.rb
     M libotr4.rb
     M libpng12.rb
     M libpqxx3.rb
     M libuv0.rb
     M libxml278.rb
     M llvm-gcc28.rb
     M llvm33.rb
     M llvm34.rb
     M llvm35.rb
     M llvm36.rb
     M log4cplus10.rb
     M lua53.rb
     M maven2.rb
     M maven30.rb
     M maven31.rb
     M maven32.rb
     M mkvtoolnix58.rb
     M mongodb24.rb
     M mongodb26.rb
     M mono3.rb
     M mpfr2.rb
     M mysql51.rb
     M mysql55.rb
     M nasm21106.rb
     M nettle3.rb
     M node010.rb
     M node04.rb
     M node06.rb
     M node08.rb
     M nu0.rb
     M objective-caml312.rb
     M open-mpi16.rb
     M openjpeg20.rb
     M openjpeg21.rb
     M openssl098.rb
     M openssl101.rb
     M pandoc-citeproc05.rb
     M pandoc1131.rb
     M percona-server55.rb
     M perl514.rb
     M perl516.rb
     M perl518.rb
     M phantomjs17.rb
     M phantomjs182.rb
     M phantomjs192.rb
     M phantomjs198.rb
     M play12.rb
     M play13.rb
     M play22.rb
     M postgis15.rb
     M postgis20.rb
     M postgresql8.rb
     M postgresql9.rb
     M postgresql91.rb
     M postgresql92.rb
     M postgresql93.rb
     M povray36.rb
     M ppl011.rb
     M ppl10.rb
     M protobuf240a.rb
     M protobuf241.rb
     M protobuf250.rb
     M qt52.rb
     M rabbitmq30.rb
     M raptor1.rb
     M redis1310.rb
     M redis24.rb
     M redis26.rb
     M redis28.rb
     M riak132.rb
     M ruby182.rb
     M ruby186.rb
     M ruby187.rb
     M ruby192.rb
     M ruby193.rb
     M ruby20.rb
     M ruby21.rb
     M scala210.rb
     M scala29.rb
     M solr14.rb
     M solr36.rb
     M solr4.rb
     M sonar4.rb
     M squid2.rb
     M subversion16.rb
     M subversion17.rb
     M swig2.rb
     M swig304.rb
     M syncthing010.rb
     M thrift090.rb
     M tomcat6.rb
     M tomcat7.rb
     M unison232.rb
     M unison240.rb
     M v8-315.rb
     M valgrind36.rb
     M valgrind38.rb
     M varnish3.rb
     M virtuoso616.rb
     M zeromq22.rb
     M zeromq3.rb
     M zeromq32.rb
    Restored your changes:
     M README.md
     M allegro4.rb
     M android-ndk-r10c.rb
     M android-ndk-r9d.rb
     M ansible14.rb
     M antlr2.rb
     M apache-spark121.rb
     M appledoc20.rb
     M appledoc21.rb
     M appledoc22.rb
     M autoconf213.rb
     M autoconf264.rb
     M automake112.rb
     M bash-completion2.rb
     M bind99.rb
     M bison27.rb
     M boost149.rb
     M boost150.rb
     M boost155.rb
     M boot2docker133.rb
     M boot2docker141.rb
     M camlp5-606.rb
     M cassandra-0.6.rb
     M cassandra10.rb
     M cassandra12.rb
     M cassandra20.rb
     M clojure14.rb
     M cloog-ppl015.rb
     M cloog018.rb
     M cmake28.rb
     M cmake30.rb
     M cmake31.rb
     M coq83.rb
     M cvsps2.rb
     M docker133.rb
     M docker141.rb
     M docker150.rb
     M doxygen1831.rb
     M drush4.rb
     M drush5.rb
     M duplicity06.rb
     M eigen2.rb
     M elasticsearch-0.20.rb
     M elasticsearch090.rb
     M elasticsearch11.rb
     M elasticsearch12.rb
     M elasticsearch13.rb
     M elasticsearch14.rb
     M erlang-r13.rb
     M erlang-r14.rb
     M erlang-r15.rb
     M erlang-r16.rb
     M gawk3.rb
     M gcc43.rb
     M gcc44.rb
     M gcc45.rb
     M gcc46.rb
     M gcc47.rb
     M gcc48.rb
     M gcc49.rb
     M gcc5.rb
     M gdal111.rb
     M gecode373.rb
     M giflib5.rb
     M git-tf-2.0.2.rb
     M glfw2.rb
     M glfw3.rb
     M gmp4.rb
     M gnupg21.rb
     M gnuplot4.rb
     M gnutls34.rb
     M go12.rb
     M go13.rb
     M gradle110.rb
     M gradle112.rb
     M gradle16.rb
     M gradle18.rb
     M gradle20.rb
     M gradle21.rb
     M gradle221.rb
     M grails13.rb
     M grails20.rb
     M grails21.rb
     M grails22.rb
     M grails223.rb
     M grails224.rb
     M grails23.rb
     M gsl114.rb
     M gst-ffmpeg010.rb
     M gst-plugins-bad010.rb
     M gst-plugins-base010.rb
     M gst-plugins-good010.rb
     M gst-plugins-ugly010.rb
     M gst-python010.rb
     M gst-rtsp010.rb
     M gstreamer010.rb
     M guile18.rb
     M hadoop0202.rb
     M hadoop121.rb
     M hadoop25.rb
     M hdf4.rb
     M hive010.rb
     M hive011.rb
     M imagemagick-ruby186.rb
     M isl011.rb
     M isl012.rb
     M isl014.rb
     M jboss-as5.rb
     M jboss-forge1.rb
     M jenkins-lts.rb
     M jetty76.rb
     M jetty8.rb
     M jpeg6b.rb
     M jpeg9.rb
     M json-c010.rb
     M kafka080.rb
     M ledger26.rb
     M leptonica169.rb
     M libcouchbase1.rb
     M libdvdcss12.rb
     M libgee08.rb
     M libmongoclient-legacy.rb
     M libmpc08.rb
     M libotr4.rb
     M libpng12.rb
     M libpqxx3.rb
     M libuv0.rb
     M libxml278.rb
     M llvm-gcc28.rb
     M llvm33.rb
     M llvm34.rb
     M llvm35.rb
     M llvm36.rb
     M log4cplus10.rb
     M lua53.rb
     M maven2.rb
     M maven30.rb
     M maven31.rb
     M maven32.rb
     M mkvtoolnix58.rb
     M mongodb24.rb
     M mongodb26.rb
     M mono3.rb
     M mpfr2.rb
     M mysql51.rb
     M mysql55.rb
     M nasm21106.rb
     M nettle3.rb
     M node010.rb
     M node04.rb
     M node06.rb
     M node08.rb
     M nu0.rb
     M objective-caml312.rb
     M open-mpi16.rb
     M openjpeg20.rb
     M openjpeg21.rb
     M openssl098.rb
     M openssl101.rb
     M pandoc-citeproc05.rb
     M pandoc1131.rb
     M percona-server55.rb
     M perl514.rb
     M perl516.rb
     M perl518.rb
     M phantomjs17.rb
     M phantomjs182.rb
     M phantomjs192.rb
     M phantomjs198.rb
     M play12.rb
     M play13.rb
     M play22.rb
     M postgis15.rb
     M postgis20.rb
     M postgresql8.rb
     M postgresql9.rb
     M postgresql91.rb
     M postgresql92.rb
     M postgresql93.rb
     M povray36.rb
     M ppl011.rb
     M ppl10.rb
     M protobuf240a.rb
     M protobuf241.rb
     M protobuf250.rb
     M qt52.rb
     M rabbitmq30.rb
     M raptor1.rb
     M redis1310.rb
     M redis24.rb
     M redis26.rb
     M redis28.rb
     M riak132.rb
     M ruby182.rb
     M ruby186.rb
     M ruby187.rb
     M ruby192.rb
     M ruby193.rb
     M ruby20.rb
     M ruby21.rb
     M scala210.rb
     M scala29.rb
     M solr14.rb
     M solr36.rb
     M solr4.rb
     M sonar4.rb
     M squid2.rb
     M subversion16.rb
     M subversion17.rb
     M swig2.rb
     M swig304.rb
     M syncthing010.rb
     M thrift090.rb
     M tomcat6.rb
     M tomcat7.rb
     M unison232.rb
     M unison240.rb
     M v8-315.rb
     M valgrind36.rb
     M valgrind38.rb
     M varnish3.rb
     M virtuoso616.rb
     M zeromq22.rb
     M zeromq3.rb
     M zeromq32.rb
    Already up-to-date.
    ➜  ~
```

tried to reset, wasn't lucky

```
    $ sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local
    $ cd /usr/local
    $ git fetch origin
    $ git reset —hard origin/master
```

Also tried to get .gitignore

```
    cd $(brew --repository) && curl -LO https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew/master/.gitignore
```

None of the above have corrected it!

Comment: Not certain of these ideas, hence the comment rather than an answer... I think it is `git checkout -- README.md` etc to forget about all your local changes on that file. And also maybe `git reset -hard origin master` rather than with the slash, but I am no expert.

Comment: I had the same issue after updating to OS X El Capitan. A `git reset --hard origin/master` in `/usr/local` fixed the issue for me. Your code example has `-hard` with just one dash...